# Rails 5 - How to convert from array to activerecord relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord

In rails 5, I have written a query like `User.where("id = #{current_user.id}").include_associations.order(created_at: :desc)`

This is returning a list like `[#<User id: 15, name: "Shruthi", ...>]`.

How can I get only activerecord data here(array is not required)?
I want a list like `#<User id: 15, name: "Shruthi", ...>`

Comment: `.where` returns a relation representing a collection of results since 0 or more results are possible in general with a `.where` condition. An activerecord instance is just one result. What is it you want? Just the first result of the `where`? In that case, just write `User.where(...).first`, or use `.find` instead of `.where`.

Comment: If  you want to each of the multiple ActiveRecords one at a time, just use `.each <block>` after your `.order(...)` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the associations for the current user and you've set up the 'has_many' correctly you can do...

```
current_user.associations.order(created_at: :desc)
```

This will give you all the association records, and (of course) the current_user information like `id` and `name` are available directly from the current user.

This will be an ActiveRecord::Relation and you can iterate over it so, yes, it'll behave like an array.  If you want all the list, you want an array or array-like structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. Add `.first` to the query.
2. Use `User.find(current_user.id)...`

Comment: I want all the list not single row.

Comment: @ShruthiR all of the list cannot be represented as a single ActiveRecord. So your original question is unclear.

Comment: You cannot retrieve a list that is not an Array. If you want more than one record, an array of records will be there.

Answer (score 0):

You want list as well then you have to iterate over an array

```
users = User.where("id = #{current_user.id}").include_associations.order(created_at: :desc)
users.each do |user|
  #user is activerecord data here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an alternative for you, example -

```
 user_array = User.where("id = #{current_user.id}").include_associations.order(created_at: :desc)
active_record_of_users = User.where(id: user_array.map(&:id))
```